# Moving objects along predefined paths with webgl

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, webgl

I've read the "learning webgl" tutorial, but it does not explain everything. Something like google experiments with webgl are amazing, but I've been wondering... how do you move a 3D object along a custom path to swing into the scene or create a custom transition?

webgl -> opengl in web, so how do you do that in opengl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you're looking for is pretty common functionality, but it is hard to find concrete examples showing how to do it.

the easiest way i have found to do it is using Apple's J3DIMath.js webgl library.
you basically want to define a "camera" perspective matrix, then move the camera along a predefined path of vertices through your 3d space. as you move along the "track" of vertices, at each draw frame you can call the function J3DIMatrix4.lookat(), passing it the position vector along the path, the direction to look at, and the "up" direction, and it will create the appearance of a moving camera.

i hope this helps!

[J3DIMath.js](http://code.google.com/p/simple3d/source/browse/util/J3DIMath.js?name=2331114a4f&r=460e2b7edc186ef13809350290dc61a8c30e2f4c)

Comment: Thank you. In your experience, is this method used or just a starting point?

Comment: Don't vandalize your post.